# How to change the value of disabled with aura:if?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, aura, aura-if

I have a few text input fields and 1 `lightning:input type="file"`:

```
<lightning:input type="file" name="file" accept="image/jpg" id="photoFile" onchange="{!c.handleFile}" disabled="true"/>
```

I have to change it to `disabled="false"`, if all text input fields aren't empty. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use aura:if for this. Just set the value to an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="fileInputDisabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<lightning:input type="file" name="file" accept="image/jpg" 
  id="photoFile" onchange="{!c.handleFile}" disabled="{!v.fileInputDisabled}"/>
```

To actually change the value, use aura:valueChanged handlers as appropriate.

---

## Demo

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="demo" onchange="{!c.update}" label="Value 1" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="demo" onchange="{!c.update}" label="Value 2" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="demo" onchange="{!c.update}" label="Value 3" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="demo" onchange="{!c.update}" label="Value 4" />
    <lightning:input name="file" type="file" label="file" disabled="{!v.disabled}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    update: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.disabled", !component.find("demo").every(field => !!field.get("v.value")));
    }
})
```